# need help pattern match on particular column and update another that match found using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have this file, `raw.csv`, on Linux:

```
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category
1,customer_ip_address_nbr,,Ab,cd
2,customer_ipaddress,,Ab,cd
3,customer_ipaddress,,Ab,cd
4,Shipaddress,,Ab,cd
5,Ship_Ip_adress,,Ab,cd
6,Ipaddress,,Ab,cd
7,xyz,,Ab,cd
```

I want to print all lines where the second column fulfills this condition:

(contains "ip" and contains "address") and (doesn't contain "ship")

I tried:

```
awk ' $2 = ((/ip/ && addres) && !(ship)) print $1,$2,$3="IP address",$4,45 raw.csv
```

desired output :

```
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category
1,customer_ip_address_nbr,IP address,Ab,cd
2,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
3,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
5,Ship_Ip_adress,IP address,Ab,cd
6,Ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
```

Comment: can you state the conditions you want to meet ? (string IP or addresse or ship )

Comment: I've added condition in question

Comment: The expected output contains `Ship`. Is `Ship` ok, but `ship` not ok?

Comment: Please be aware that line#5 has a typo in "adress"... and yet it shows up in the output despite not meeting the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR == 1 { print; next }
    { k = tolower($2) }
    (k ~ /ip/) && (k ~ /address/) && (k !~ /ship/) {
        $3 = "IP address"
        print
    }
' file
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category
1,customer_ip_address_nbr,IP address,Ab,cd
2,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
3,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
6,Ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
```

Comment: the input line number 5 is missing from the output.

Comment: @Rakesh right because input line number 5 doesn't match the criteria to be output, it has `adress` instead of `address`. But [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591773/need-help-pattern-match-on-particular-column-and-update-another-that-match-found/591806?noredirect=1#comment1103695_591773) you already knew that so not sure why you're commenting on it. I'm also not sure why you're commenting on it just under my answer when it's not present in the output from any of the answers (except yours because you apparently changed the input data).

Comment: because I am assuming it to be a typo.

Comment: You already commented on that under the question. Again, not sure why you added that comment under my answer given you know why that lines not in the output and it's not in anyone else's output either for the same reason you already identified.

Comment: Apparently I didn't realize that.But even if you fix the typo would you be getting rhe output?

Comment: No because it contains `Ship`. If line 4 which contains `ip`, `address`, and `Ship` shouldn't be output then neither should line 5 which also contains `ip`, `address`, and `Ship` and given the OPs requirement to `(contains "ip" and contains "address") and (doesn't contain "ship")` and they have other output and comments that indicate they want the match to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } FNR == 1 { print; next } /[iI]p/ && /[aA]ddress/ && !/[sS]hip/ { $3 = "IP address"; print }' file
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category
1,customer_ip_address_nbr,IP address,Ab,cd
2,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
3,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
6,Ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
```

This prints the first line from the file unconditionally.

It then tests for a few patterns, making sure to allow a variation in case on the initial character. The test for `Ship` and `ship` is done so that it's *true* if the pattern *does't* match (with `!`).

If a line passes all tests, its 3rd column is updated and the modified line is printed.

If the substrings that we want to match is to be matched in the 2nd column *only*, then perform the tests on the contents of that column:

```
awk -F , '
    BEGIN    { OFS=FS }
    FNR == 1 { print; next }
    $2 ~ /[iI]p/ && $2 ~ /[aA]ddress/ && $2 !~ /[sS]hip/ {
        $3 = "IP address"
        print
    }' file
```

Note the use of `!~` in the last test.

This all assumes that the input ifle is a *simple CSV* file, i.e. that no field contains an embedded comma or newline character (which is allowed in properly quoted fields in CSV files).

Comment: (contains "ip" and contains "address") and (doesn't contain "ship") >>> condition should first include bracket between ip and addres and then a seperate match doesn't contain ship

Comment: Is it possible whole pattern search as case insensitive ?

Comment: @user3016638 `(A && B) && (!C)` is the same as `A && B && !C` So I'm not sure what you want to say with your first comment.

Comment: @user3016638 You would have to test e.g. `/[aA][dD][dD][rR][eE][sS][sS]/` if you wanted to allow for variations of case in every character, or `/address|ADDRESS|Address/` if you want to allow for those three variations of the word.

Comment: I ran you code on raw file its giving output for entry "emailaddress" where its not having ip

Comment: @user3016638 What did that line look like?

Comment: @user3016638 `subscription` contains `ip`.

Comment: there are lines that has only emailaddress 5e0f17aec4b3ad253501a043,emailaddress,,,,HadoopPROD,iah_rally_analysis_base,v_owner,Proximity,,FALSE,TRUE
5e0f17aec4b3ad253501a3e5,emailaddress,,,,HadoopPROD,iah_rally_ingest,oneit_us

Comment: @user3016638 Yes, that line would not be extracted. It's unclear whether you want it extracted or not.

Comment: I don't want output when its not matching the criteria. In this case emailaddress will not match our criteria

Comment: @user3016638 So, why did you mention that line of data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109091/discussion-between-user3016638-and-kusalananda).

Answer (score 1):

[Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) is nice for this kind of thing:

```
$ mlr --csvlite \
    filter '$field_name =~ "[Ii]p" && $field_name =~ "[Aa]ddress" && $field_name !=~ "[Ss]hip"' \
    then put -S '$field_friendly_name = "IP address"' raw.csv
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category
1,customer_ip_address_nbr,IP address,Ab,cd
2,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
3,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
6,Ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v q="'" --field-separator ',' '(tolower($2) ~ /ip/)&&(tolower($2) !~ /ship/)&&(tolower($2) ~ /address/)&&($3="IP Address") {print $0}' raw.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Done with python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
j=re.compile(r'ip',re.IGNORECASE)
o=re.compile(r'address',re.IGNORECASE)
z=re.compile(r'ship',re.IGNORECASE)
k=open('p.txt','r')
q=k.readline()
print q.strip()
for i in k:
    if re.search (j,i) and (o,i):
        if not re.search(z,i):
            print i.strip()
```

output

```
_id,field_name,field_friendly_name,purpose_of_use,category
1,customer_ip_address_nbr,,Ab,cd
2,customer_ipaddress,,Ab,cd
3,customer_ipaddress,,Ab,cd
6,Ipaddress,,Ab,cd
```

Answer (score 0):

Such validation tasks are tailor made for lookarounds regex.

In this particular scenario we want to select those lines that have "ip"  and the "address" should be present but mustn't see a "ship" to it's immediate left.

```
perl -F, -lane '
  s/,,/,IP address,/;
  print if $F[1] =~ \
    /(?=.*(?<!ship)address)(?=.*ip)/i;
' file
```

Output:

```
1,customer_ip_address_nbr,IP address,Ab,cd
2,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
3,customer_ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
5,Ship_Ip_address,IP address,Ab,cd
6,Ipaddress,IP address,Ab,cd
```